# In the MQTT protocol, how does a client identify a server?

Tags: mqtt, iot

I have read that the overhead is low. What does it really mean when compared to HTTP? Does it not use the ip address of the server to which a client tries to connect to? If not, how does a client connect to a server?

Answer (score 0):

Low overhead means that for a given size of messages there is very little extra information sent. It has nothing to do with broker discovery.

E.g. for a HTTP message there us a relatively large amount of HTTP Headers sent before any of the message is transmitted.

The client will connect to the broker via it's IP address. This can either be known in advance, looked up from a host name via DNS or looked up via a TXT record in the DNS for a given domain. You can see examples of broker discovery on the mqtt.org site [here](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/broker_auto-discovery)